# How to remove iPad device from App Store in developer account?

Tags: ios, ipad

How to remove an iPad device from App Store in developer account?
I am following this process from my understanding --

1. Remove the live app completely
2. Again upload a new build of the same package without Ipad device

Is it okay or I am following the incorrect procedure. Do let me know, please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove it or submit a new version. You can check which device screens your app consists of by clicking "View All Sizes in Media Manager in your developer account App page"[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, once you've released a build with iPad support, AppStore Connect will reject any future builds that don't include iPad support.

So you can't remove iPad support.

Comment: Recently I did it, AppStore never rejects the App on the basis if you are dropping out of iPad support.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this image to remove iPad from your next build:

[image: Refer this image to remove ipad from your next build]

Answer (score -2):

No need to remove your app from AppStore to support just only iPhone devices. App store connect is responsible to manage the device family support
Archive your new build with deployment info iPhone and increase version number as shown in the image [image]

- Push your new build at AppStore
- Open app store connect and select your App
- check device family support in the build metadata section